# How to calculate a triangular interpolation from values in coordinates in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

If I have a matrix with first and second columns related to coordinates and third one related to a value, how could I interpolate third column values creating iscurves and colorbar ranges?

```
M=[
342854  657145  309
342996  657287  73
343137  657428  84
342006  657145  1122
342147  657287  777
342289  657428  426
342430  657570  638
342571  657711  200
342713  657852  787
341723  657711  1141
341864  657852  555
342006  657994  1157
342147  658135  355
342289  658277  374
341299  658135  467
341440  658277  672
341582  658418  459
341723  658560  735
341864  658701  781
341016  658701  1233
341157  658842  218
341299  658984  539
341370  659054  1351];
```

and obtain something like the attached image
[image: interpolated_values]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your data is not in an uniform grid, you need to use `griddata` for interpolation.

```
[xq,yq]=meshgrid(linspace(min(M(:,1)),max(M(:,1)),100),linspace(min(M(:,2)),max(M(:,2)),100));
zq=griddata(M(:,1),M(:,2),M(:,3),xq(:),yq(:),'cubic'); %cubic for smoother results
[c,h]=contourf(xq,yq,reshape(zq,100,100));
clabel(c,h);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ander!